# Проблема с связывание Qt с Postgres

Tags: postgresql, qtcreator

QSqlDatabase: QPSQL driver not loaded
QSqlDatabase: available drivers: QSQLITE QMYSQL QMYSQL3 QODBC QODBC3 QPSQL QPSQL7

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего, плагин `qsqlpsql` не может найти путь к `libpq`.
Если у вас Linux, то необходимо либо установить в систему Postgres, либо хотя бы пакет libpq-dev.

Если же у вас Windows и Postgres установлен на машине, то нужно либо добавить в [PATH](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F)) путь к `libpq.dll` (скорее всего, он будет находиться где-то типа `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\11\bin\`), либо скопировать библиотеку и её зависимости в каталог, из которого запускается ваше приложение. Например, для 64-битной `libpq.dll` 11 версии это `libssl-1_1-x64.dll`, `libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll`, `libintl-9.dll` и `libiconv-2.dll`.